# Measuring time of async request

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, interop, bho

What HTML Document Events should I connect to, to measure time that asnchronous request took?
In synchronous request I am using BeforeNavigate2 and OnDocumentComplete events. In BeforeNavigate2 I am setting start time and finally in OnDocumentComplete I measure time that elapsed from start time.
Which html document events should I use to do similar measurement of asynchronous request.

EDIT:
Xaenec, I thought about connecting to events this way:

```
    public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        HTMLDocument doc = webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
        if (doc != null)
        {
            HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event events = (doc as HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event);
            try
            {
                events.onreadystatechange += new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onreadystatechangeEventHandler(events_onreadystatechange);
            }
            catch
            {
                events.onreadystatechange -= new HTMLDocumentEvents2_onreadystatechangeEventHandler(events_onreadystatechange);
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not know which event should I connect to, so I could make time stamp of begin async request and which event should I connect to to make time stamp of end async request.

Comment: Hard to make sense of this question, all page loads are asynchronous.

Comment: Does google maps refresh all page afther changing view? Or only part of the page is refreshed? Do you exactly know what async request is?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean javascript execution.  There are no events for that.

Comment: No, I did not think about javascript. What I have done is handling events BeforeNavigate2 and OnDocumentComplete. Thank to it I can measure time of page loading. But it works until page generates AJAX request - for example it is not working while loading maps in google maps and I want to handle it.

Comment: Guess what the J in Ajax means.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: yes, that is right. But even AJAX cause invoking on load method in html document body. isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the callback of your asynchronous request, to measure the time when it is finished. If I missunderstand your question please give more details.